# C# - Sockets not receiving all bytes

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp, serversocket

I have been struggling to fix my mistake. My client/server seems to work fine when on the same machine. When the code is executed on a different PC, for some reason only part of the bytes are reaching the server. I cannot seem to get the bytes to go through to matter how much I try. It seems the cutoff point is 367 bytes and it does not want to transfer anymore. If anyone knows what I am doing wrong, a solution would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Server:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace DMAssist
{

    // State object for reading client data asynchronously
    public class StateObject
    {
        // Client  socket.
        public Socket workSocket = null;
        // Size of receive buffer.
        public const int BufferSize = 1024;
        // Receive buffer.
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        // Received data string.
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Current URL string
    }

    public class asyncserver
    {

        public asyncserver()
        {
        }

        // Thread signal.
        public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
        {
            var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    return ip.ToString();
                }
            }
            throw new Exception("Local IP Address Not Found!");
        }

        public void StartListening()
        {
            // Data buffer for incoming data.
            byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

            // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
            // The DNS name of the computer
            // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 25599);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
            try
            {
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                listener.Listen(100);

                while (true)
                {
                    // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
                    allDone.Reset();

                    // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                    listener.BeginAccept(
                        new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                        listener);

                    // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                    allDone.WaitOne();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
            Console.Read();

        }

        public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // Signal the main thread to continue.
            allDone.Set();

            // Get the socket that handles the client request.
            Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

            // Create the state object.
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = handler;
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }


        public byte[] ObjectToByteArray(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return null;

            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }

        private Object ByteArrayToObject(byte[] arrBytes)
        {
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
            memStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
            memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            Object obj = (Object)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
            return obj;
        }


        public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            String content = String.Empty;
            String connectedAddress = String.Empty;
            // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = state.workSocket;
            IPEndPoint remoteIpEndPoint = handler.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
            connectedAddress = remoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString();

            // Read data from the client socket. 
            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Bytes read: " + bytesRead);

                // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                    state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                object rawbytes = ByteArrayToObject(state.buffer);
                netObject recvobject = (netObject)rawbytes;

                Send(handler, (object)recvobject);
            }
   }

        private void Send(Socket handler, object data)
        {
            // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
            byte[] byteData = ObjectToByteArray(data);

            // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
            handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
        }

        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
                Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
                int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
                Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                handler.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
 using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Collections;

    namespace DMAssist
    {
        public class asyncsclient {

            public asyncsclient()
            {
            }

            public byte[] ObjectToByteArray(object obj)
            {
                if (obj == null)
                    return null;

                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }

            private Object ByteArrayToObject(byte[] arrBytes)
            {
                MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
                BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
                memStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
                memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                Object obj = (Object)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
                return obj;
            }

            static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
                System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                return bytes;
            }

            static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
            {
                char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
                System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
                return new string(chars);
            }

            public object sendObject(object outgoingObject, bool expectRecieve)
            {
                try
                {

                    Socket soc = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("x.x.x.x");
                    IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ip, 25599);
                    soc.Connect(remoteEP);

                    byte[] byData = ObjectToByteArray(outgoingObject);

                    //Console.WriteLine("Array length:" + byData.Length);

                    soc.Send(byData);


                    if (expectRecieve)
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int iRx = soc.Receive(buffer);

                        object rawbytes = ByteArrayToObject(buffer);
                        netObject recvobject = (netObject)rawbytes;

                        Console.WriteLine("Writing stopped");
                        soc.Close();
                        soc.Dispose();

                        return recvobject;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        soc.Close();
                        soc.Dispose();

                        return "";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Server unreachable. Make sure server is broadcasting on port 25599 successfully.", "DMAssist Error 0xC1");
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a big difference between UDP sockets and TCP sockets.
What you are trying would work better with UDP because this protocol is more packet oriented. This means that if a server sends a certain number of bytes, the client 'might' receive the same certain number of bytes or receive nothing at all.

For TCP it is different because it is a streaming protocol which means bytes are just sent sequentially anyway the server sees fit. Usually it will try to fill up to the mtu and when you receive you will very likely receive the data in multiple chunks that you have to append yourself. TCP is a also connection oriented and reliable. Bytes are acked from the client to the server and vice versa, and retransmitted if an ack is not received in due time. This means even that packets can at the TCP level be received out of order. TCP will fit them together. You at the application level will receive everything in order.

The advice you got so far is correct, you have to keep calling receive. And this until there is nothing to receive anymore. And how do you know that there is nothing to receive anymore ? Usually that is detected by receiving a TCP message in receive with 0 length. This means that the peer has closed its end of the socket and will not send anymore. This in turn means that you can close your end of the socket.

Comment: What would it take to convert this to UDP? I am not very experienced with networking.

Comment: Different use of sockets. You don't need accept, for instance because udp does not have the concept of a connection. If you are really a beginner looking into UDP before using TCP is indeed not a bad idea. But google around a bit so you understand the concepts better. There is a UdpClient in .NET start with that one.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design.  And it's a very common mistake developers make with regards to sockets.

To receive data correctly, you need to keep receiving data in a loop until you receive the number of bytes you need.  Keep appending to your receive buffer until you get the number of bytes you need.

Some socket implementations have a the concept of a "wait for all" flag (e.g. MSG_WAITALL), but even that will return partial data if the remote closed the connection after sending.

Code defensively.  Code as if the sender is only going to send 1 byte at a time.  You'll be in good shape.

Comment: I tried doing a loop to keep appending bytes to the total, but for some reason the thread times out whenever I run it with a loop.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your code, There  might be more data, so you store the data received so far. But you don't have the code get the rest of the data.

MSDN has an example on how to do this correctly:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: the example itself works fine for me, so maybe you made some modification ?

Comment: So does the original code work on your computer? If so, please provide your modified version so we can figure it out what goes wrong ..

Comment: I updated my main post with my current server and client code.

Comment: I had it in there earlier, I removed it because it completely broke it to the point that not even my local machine worked anymore, hence why I reverted it. Perhaps I did it incorrectly? I am not very experienced with sockets.

Comment: just remember you have to do
`client.BeginReceive( state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);` 
over and over until everything is recieved.

Comment: You should first test the original code, and then replace everything related to `response` into your object serialize/deserailize part

Answer (score 0):

From winsock2.h:
#define MSG_WAITALL     0x8             /* do not complete until packet is completely filled */

You can add this option to your .net stream socket receive like this:
socket.Receive(buffer, (SocketFlags)0x8)

This should preserve message boundaries much like you're accustomed with dgram sockets.