# why is C# getting a distorted image from a python server?

Tags: python, wpf, image, sockets, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to transfer camera stream from my raspberry pi to pc as fast as possible. Now I'm trying to transfer it using MJPEG method. So I have a python script on my raspberry as server:

```py
import io
import socket
import struct
import time
import cv2

class SplitFrames(object):
    def __init__(self, connection):
       self.connection = connection
       self.stream = io.BytesIO()
       self.count = 0

    def write(self, buf):
        if buf.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
            # Start of new frame; send the old one's length
            # then the data
            size = self.stream.tell()
            if size > 0:
                self.connection.write(struct.pack('<L', size))
                self.connection.flush()
                self.stream.seek(0)
                self.connection.write(self.stream.read(size))
                self.count += 1
                self.stream.seek(0)
        self.stream.write(buf)


server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8001))
server_socket.listen(0)

# Accept a single connection and make a file-like object out of it
connection = server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('wb')
try:
    output = SplitFrames(connection)
    time.sleep(2)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        ret, img = cap.read()
        ret, jpg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
        output.write(jpg.tostring())
    connection.write(struct.pack('<L', 0))
finally:
    connection.close()
    server_socket.close()
```

that works well. Also I have a python script on my pc as client, that also works well and I receive a good stream:

```py
import io
import socket
import struct
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Start a socket listening for connections on 0.0.0.0:8000 (0.0.0.0 means
# all interfaces)


client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect(("10.12.34.2", 8001))
connection = client_socket.makefile('rb')

try:
    while True:
        # Read the length of the image as a 32-bit unsigned int. If the
        # length is zero, quit the loop
        a = connection.read(struct.calcsize('<L'))
        image_len = struct.unpack('<L', a)[0]
        if not image_len:
            break
        # Construct a stream to hold the image data and read the image
        # data from the connection
        image_stream = io.BytesIO()
        image_stream.write(connection.read(image_len))
        # Rewind the stream, open it as an image with PIL and do some
        # processing on it
        image_stream.seek(0)
        image = Image.open(image_stream)
        cv_image = np.array(image)
        cv2.imshow('Stream',cv_image)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

finally:
    connection.close()
    client_socket.close()
```

But I needed to write client side on WPF, so I wrote it, but it doesn't work well. I receive distorted stream and after a few seconds WPF app breaks and gives me `System.IO.FileFormatException`. Here is the image from WPF:

[image: cracked image]

What could be the reason of this? Thanks for any advice!
Here is the minimum reproducible code:
C#

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WPFTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private static bool connected = false;
        private Socket sct;
        private IPEndPoint ipPoint;

        // TCP
        private bool stopThread = false;
        private Thread thread;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    //this.ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), int.Parse("8001", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                    this.ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.12.34.2"), int.Parse("8001", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    return;
                }

                this.sct = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
                stopThread = false;

                thread = new Thread(() => { Listening(); });
                thread.IsBackground = false;
                thread.Start();

                connected = true;
            }
        }

        private void DisconnectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (connected)
            {
                StopListening();

                connected = false;
            }
        }

        private void Listening()
        {
            try
            {
                sct.Connect(ipPoint);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                StopListening();
                connected = false;
                return;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            try
            {
                while (!this.stopThread)
                {
                    byte[] data = GetInputBytes(sct);

                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        SetImage(data);
                    });
                }
                sct.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                sct.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                StopListening();
            }
        }

        public void StopListening()
        {
            this.stopThread = true;
            try
            {
                thread.Abort();
                sct.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                sct.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //
            }
        }

        private void SetImage(byte[] array)
        {
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            using (var mem = new MemoryStream(array))
            {
                mem.Position = 0;
                image.BeginInit();
                image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
                image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                image.UriSource = null;
                image.StreamSource = mem;
                image.EndInit();
            }
            image.Freeze();

            ImageCamera.Source = image;
        }

        public static byte[] GetInputBytes(Socket clientSocket)
        {
            byte[] rcvLenBytes = new byte[4];
            clientSocket.Receive(rcvLenBytes);
            UInt32 rcvLen = BytesToInt(rcvLenBytes);

            byte[] rcvBytes;
            byte[] clientData;
            List<byte> rcvBytesList = new List<byte>();
            int totalBytes = 0;
            while (totalBytes < rcvLen)
            {
                if (rcvLen - totalBytes < 262144)
                {
                    clientData = new byte[rcvLen - totalBytes];
                }
                else
                {
                    clientData = new byte[262144];
                }
                int bytesReceived = clientSocket.Receive(clientData);
                rcvBytesList.AddRange(clientData);
                totalBytes += bytesReceived;
            }
            rcvBytes = rcvBytesList.ToArray();

            return rcvBytes;
        }

        public static UInt32 BytesToInt(byte[] arr)
        {
            UInt32 wd = ((UInt32)arr[3] << 24) | ((UInt32)arr[2] << 16) | ((UInt32)arr[1] << 8) | (UInt32)arr[0];
            return wd;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```xml
<Window x:Class="WPFTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="200px"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="220px" ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="180px" ></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Height="60" Width="140" Content="Connect" x:Name="ConnectButton" FontSize="20" FontFamily="LilyUPC" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20, 80, 20, 0" Click="ConnectButton_Click"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Height="60" Width="140" Content="Disconnect" x:Name="DisconnectButton" FontSize="20" FontFamily="LilyUPC" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20, 80, 20, 0" Click="DisconnectButton_Click"/>


        <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="10" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" x:Name="ImageCamera"></Image>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: BytesToInt() -> [ToInt32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint32?view=net-5.0#System_BitConverter_ToInt32_System_Byte___System_Int32_)?

Comment: Why always reallocate the clientData buffer? IMHO, the problem is in `rcvBytesList.AddRange(clientData);` where you might add more bytes than were received.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thanks for the answer! But it doesn't add more bytes then received. It won't work without this. I have already asked about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68114173/problem-with-transfering-image-from-java-to-c-sharp-using-socket-connection

Comment: "But it doesn't add more bytes then received." Quite sure it will. AddRange adds the whole buffer. How should it know how many bytes were received?

Comment: OK, I believe you.  But how, then, to rewrite the acceptance of the data so that they are all accepted? Edit: I understood you at all. Thanks! I will try to rewrite it tomorrow when I will be at my workshop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ThomasWeller for their answer in comments! As they said:

> AddRange adds the whole buffer. How should it know how many bytes were received?

So I rewrote my receive method like this:

```cs
public static byte[] GetInputBytes(Socket clientSocket)
{
    byte[] rcvLenBytes = new byte[4];
    clientSocket.Receive(rcvLenBytes);
    UInt32 rcvLen = BytesToInt(rcvLenBytes);

    byte[] rcvBytes;
    byte[] clientData;
    List<byte> rcvBytesList = new List<byte>();
    int totalBytes = 0;
    while (totalBytes < rcvLen)
    {
        if (rcvLen - totalBytes < 262144)
        {
            clientData = new byte[rcvLen - totalBytes];
        }
        else
        {
            clientData = new byte[262144];
        }
        int bytesReceived = clientSocket.Receive(clientData);
        rcvBytesList.AddRange(clientData.Take(bytesReceived).ToArray());
        totalBytes += bytesReceived;
    }
    rcvBytes = rcvBytesList.ToArray();

    return rcvBytes;
}
```

Changed line is: `rcvBytesList.AddRange(clientData.Take(bytesReceived).ToArray());`
It works fine now.